# When using Chrome, why does Twitter's home page redirect me to a search for "searchTerms"?

Tags: twitter, google-chrome

This has been going on for some time. Whenever I type `twitter.com` into Chrome's omnibar, I am redirected to `https://twitter.com/search/%7BsearchTerms%7D?source=desktop-search`. Given the tweets showing there, this seems to be a common problem, though my searches only turned up one guy who recorded a [video describing the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwnCjw_t6Wo).

After clicking Twitter's Home button, I wind up at the home page I expected to reach in the first place.

I have been able to reproduce this on Chrome on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. It doesn't seem to affect other browsers such as Firefox. I have cleared cache, cookies, tried a completely different machine, the usual stuff.

My current environment is: Chrome `Version 22.0.1229.94 m` on Windows 8.
I have also experienced this on many previous versions of Chrome, running on Fedora 17 and OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Search redirects in Chrome more often than not mean that there's a custom Search URL defined under Search settings.

You can check this from Chrome Menu → Settings → Manage Search Engines (or by pasting `chrome://settings/searchEngines` in the omnibar. If there's one defined for twitter, delete that entry and it should work fine after that.

Comment: I removed the entry for Twitter and the problem is gone. I never really wanted to search Twitter from the address bar.

Comment: I wonder how a small set of us created this search rule by mistake. I lived with this issue for ~7 days before searching for this fix. :P

Comment: Finally fixed this issue after 5 years+. Thanks!

Comment: This solution certainly worked for me, but I'm curious why this seemingly only affected Twitter.  I also had a search engine for airbnb (and many others) in my list, but going to airbnb.com didn't bring me to the airbnb search page.